# How does soundmanager interpret a soundcloud stream?

Tags: soundcloud, soundmanager2

using the "inline player" demo.

```
 <li><a href="http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/42021012/stream.json?client_id=[myclientID]">play song</a></li>
```

that will take me to a mp3 link, but since it has more parameters at the end, soundmanager doesn't load it as a mp3.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding &filename=soundcloud.mp3 at the end.

```
 <li><a href="http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/42021012/stream.json?client_id=[myclientID]&filename=soundcloud.mp3">play song</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try to add `type="audio/mpeg"` in your code like this:

```
<li>
    <a type="audio/mpeg" class="sm2_button" 
        href="https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/214947467/stream?client_id=THE_CLIENT_ID">
        your eyes (title track) with intro
    </a>
</li>
```

It, solved the same problem I was having.