# Use Soundmanager2 to play Soundcloud stream_url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, streaming, soundcloud, soundmanager2

I have a rails app in which I am trying to allow users to submit a link to a song on Soundcloud and make the song available for them to stream on my app using a custom Soundmanager2 player.

I can successfully obtain the songs 'stream_url' and other information using the '/resolve' method as follows:

```
<% client = Soundcloud.new(:client_id => 'SC_CLIENT_ID') %>
<% track = client.get('/resolve', :url => "<url-to-song-on-soundcloud>") %>
```

However when I plug the 'stream_url' into the player (in this case the [Soundmanager Inline Player](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/page-player/)) including my client_id in the stream url like so:

```
<li><a href="<%= track.stream_url %>?client_id=1234567890abcdefghtijkl1234">Play Song</a></li>
```

and click on the link, it takes me off-page to the sound file link instead of playing it in the custom player on my page (similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885100/how-does-soundmanager-interpret-a-soundcloud-stream)).

I would like for the song to stream using my (in this case the SM2 inline player referenced above) player without leaving the page. Thanks in advance for any help and insight.

Comment: Figured this one out. What worked for me was adding type="audio/mp3" to the <a> tag.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to comment the lines in `inlineplayer.js`

```
if (!o.href || (!sm.canPlayLink(o) && !self.classContains(o,self.playableClass)) || self.classContains(o,self.excludeClass)) {
      return true;
    }
```